# how to transfer google contacts on S3 to phone memory for car syncing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, gmail

new car has mobile sync which recognises samsung SIII, the old car didn't. Unfortunately all the contacts on my phone are in "google" contacts rather than the phone which the car system syncs with. How can I transfer the google contacts to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the phone you have the contacts on... so I will try a general option answer: go to contacts and use the available options: e.g. Import/Export or "batch operation" followed by "select all" and "share".

other options are available just think out of the closet.